# How i can set value by another field model to model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have models

```
class Event(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField()


class Ticket(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
```

How i can set model ticket field event, event with some_field field?
Example:

```
Ticket.objects.create(event__some_field = 'value')
```

how can you achieve this?

ps. i can't use ticket.event_id = event_id and ticket.event = event in my situation (i don't want to request to database)

Comment: But at this point your `ticket` has not been linked to an `event` object in the first place, you will first need to assign one, for example with `ticket.event = myevent`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but let's say that I already have an event created, and I do not want to make a request for get event

Comment: Do you know the event_id of the event? If so you could set ticket.event_id=event_id(this will not make a "request" to the database).

Comment: ticket.event_id=event_id(this will not make a "request" to the database) - really? :(

Comment: Yes, it will not make a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create and save the Event instance separate from creating the Ticket.

```
event = Event(some_field='value')
event.save()

ticket = Ticket()
ticket.event = event
ticket.save()
```

And if you wanted to update an already existing event related to a ticket:

```
ticket.event.some_field = "new value"
ticket.event.save()
# no need to save ticket here, because nothing has changed in the relationship between ticket and event
```

Comment: i have been events when i create a ticket, just i don't want to make a request to database

Comment: Do you mean you already have the `event` instance? Or that you don't have it and you want to create a ticket for an event you don't hold in memory, but without hitting the DB?

Comment: no, i don't have event instance, but i have events in database

Comment: i don't want to make request to database for get event next create ticket

Comment: Do you have the event id locally?

Comment: okey,  i solved my problem, I am all like that need make request to database for get event before create ticket

Comment: Yep, or if you did have the event id you could do `ticket = Ticket(event_id=some_event_id) 
  ticket.save()`